# Why can't a Jew be the agent of a non Jew

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law

I was told in an answer to one of my questions that in Shulchan Aruch Hoshen Mishpat 188:1) it says Jew cannot be the agent of a non Jew and I saw it again in this schul handout below.

What is the scope of this invalidity (I.e. Not an agent for things involving an issue or halachic change but ok for business) and what is the derivation of this halacha?

[Business Halacha](http://businesshalacha.com/en/system/files_force/BW%20354%20Tzav%205777.pdf?download=1)

Comment: the attached pdf explains why very clearly. what exactly are you unsure about?

Comment: No it doesn't. It just says that a Jew cannot serve as a halachic agent of a non Jew.

Comment: I understand the question as whether a Jew may serve as an agent to a Gentile in a *non-halachic*, context, for example as a real estate agent, attorney, accountant, tax preparer, estate manager, etc.

Comment: I don't think it is forbidden, I think it is just ineffective. Remember, in Talmud times, there was no difference between secular and halachic courts - the Nasi reported to the King of Persia and was responsible for managing the Jews in the Empire.

Comment: This could be helpful https://www.ou.org/life/torah/mm_shelichut/